# assembly max int divide

Tags: c++, c, assembly, x86

I have the following program, which is getting 2 unsigned long numbers (%u), x and y,
then divides x by y and printing the result in this format: X.YZ only.

It works great for all the regular inputs, such as: 3/4 = 0.75, 10/5=2.00, 19/1000=0.01 and so on.
But when I'm trying to 2^31/2, I get a "core dumped" error.
(2^31=2147483648).

Any ideas why? I guess I'm getting garbage values somewhere, somehow, but couldn't figure out where and why.

```
format: .string "Divide : %u / %u = %u.%.2d\n"

# operation divide
movl    %ebx,   %eax    #%eax=x
cltd    #sign extend eax to edx
divl    %esi    #x=x/y
pushl   %eax    #save %eax on stack
movl    %edx,   %eax    #%eax=xmody
cltd    #sign extend eax to edx
movl    $100,   %ecx    #%ecx=100
mull    %ecx    #multiply xmody by 100
divl    %esi    #divide by y
movl    %eax,   %edx
popl    %eax

pushl   %edx
pushl   %eax    #push x/y
pushl   %esi    #push y
pushl   %ebx    #push x
pushl   $format
call    printf
```

Thanks alot! :D

edit:
for clarification, I expect that 1073741824 (which is the result of the division) to be on %eax, and since 2147483648 divides by two, the modulo should be 0.

So in the result I should get: 1073741824.00, but as you can see it doesn't happen..

Answer (score 2):

You sign-extend 2^31 to 64 bits, that means it becomes 0xffffffff80000000 which when divided by 2 (using unsigned arithmetic) results in an overflow. Apparently your input is unsigned, so you should use zero-extension (ie. just clear `edx`). With that it produces the expected output:

```
$ ./a.out
Divide : 2147483648 / 2 = 1073741824.00
```